# Word for continually referencing something in writing (i.e. harp on about)

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, adjectives

I think it's an adjective (maybe there is a verb form). It means something like oversaturating writing or speech with references to something. Harping on something. Stuffing or fattening speech with references to a certain subject. I heard it and now I cannot remember it for the life of me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked a [thesaurus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/harp) to see if a word pops out?  Can you provide more context and a sample sentence where you might use this word?

Comment: Maybe **ingeminate**? Doesn't sound quite right. I think the word has a sort of negative connotation. As though heavy-handedly repeating something to make a point.

Comment: [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/pontificate)'s definition of **pontificate**
   (verb): 
'To pontificate is to express your opinion in an annoying way, often because you go on too long or because you are too much of a know-it-all.' But questions including 'it means something like ...' are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: One of my teachers always used to say to us when writing an essay, 'Don't **go off on a tangent**.'

Comment: Some context would be helpful (as usual). What is the reason that this person is repeating themselves, for instance?

Comment: *pleonasm*, perhaps?

Comment: "dogmatic" could work in some circumstances, not in others

Comment: **redundancy** *the use of words or data that could be omitted without loss of meaning or function; repetition or superfluity of information.*

Answer (score 1):

> **perseverate**
>
> verb
>
> 1. to repeat something insistently or redundantly
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/perseverate)]

Answer (score 0):

Obvious option --

Repetitious : tediously repetitive

> His writing is monotonous, tedious and repetitious. No wonder he became a __________ (*just the right profession, methinks!*)

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/repetitious

When a student would submit a pompously worded or tediously repetitious answer, an old English teacher I know of used to down-mark it with the remark *'inundated with redundance.'*